# UITableView make the headerView not scrollable

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nstableheaderview

How to make the tableView "headerView" not scrollable.

Comment: Put it outside of the UITableView (on the top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one section, you can simply not use headerView at all and add a UIView above the UITableView

Comment: The problem that I need to add UISearchBar, and when I follow what you are saying, the UISearchBar became inactive!

Comment: you want a not-scrollable view between the UISearchBar and the first cell?

Comment: Solved by adding it to the ViewController's view (but first to overcome on the issue that it don't full fill the screen width, I added it first to the tableHeaderView ) `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
[viewController.view addSubview:searchBar]`