# make stable Table Header View

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

i have 4 buttons in `headerView`, i just want them stable on the screen at top when we scroll the tableView, How to make it stable (constant at 1 place even we scroll table)

Comment: add that four buttons in your header section of UITableView

Comment: This is not possible in the way you described. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415756/uitableview-make-the-headerview-not-scrollable

Comment: @Prateek:yeah already i have in headersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible so make one new view and set it above the tableview.